# Array.indexOf() return confusing results JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

So I am trying to return a number for what week day it is given a string like `'tue'`.
So i figured I would get the index of the string `'tue'` in an array that contains the week days

```js
week_days = ['sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat'];

var date = new Date();

var first_month_day = String(new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1).toString().slice(0, 4).toLowerCase());

var indexOf = week_days.indexOf(first_month_day)
return indexOf;
```

`first_month_day` = `'tue'` as of today when I evaluate that code.
therfore I would assume that running

```js
week_day.indexOf(first_month_day)
```

would return `2` but instead i get `-1`. So if instead of running the above if i do

```js
week_days.indexOf('tue')
```

I get the desired `2` I have ensured that first_month_day is a string using `typeof` and everything I am just at a loss as to why it keeps returning `-1` whenever I know it exists inside the array.

Comment: Consider debugging issues first - `first_month_day` is `'undefined'`

Comment: `.slice(0, 4)` will always give a string of length 4 (assuming the pre-sliced string has length at least 4), so it can't be `tue`. Did you mean `.slice(0, 3)`?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Robin Zigmond said, .slice(0, 4) will give a string with a length of 4, so you were getting "tue " from firstMonthDay  instead of "tue".

```js
const weekDays = ['sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat'];

const date = new Date();

const firstMonthDay = String(new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1).toString().slice(0, 3).toLowerCase());

const index = weekDays.indexOf(firstMonthDay);
console.log(index);
```